# Subverison client (Cornerstone) use is resulting in duplicate/backup copies of files being created within working copy

Tags: svn, centos, samba, cornerstone

I am facing a strange situation where backup copies of files are being generated with a "._" prefix when I interact with them in my subversion client (Cornerstone).

I have used this client for years in Mac with no issues. Recently, I switched my file system to a shared Network drive in a machine with CentOS 7 with SAMBA file sharing.

I added the Working Copy (from the network drive) to Cornerstone while continuing to work from the Mac machine. Now, when I interact with files in Cornerstone, i.e. revert changes or commit changes, a backup file is auto-created at the working copy location for each file affected. For example -

Original files:

> my_php_file.php, my_js_file.js, my_css_file.css

Would have copies named:

> ._my_php_file.php, ._my_js_file.js, ._my_css_file.css

Example: https://snag.gy/2yFTJl.jpg

They show up in the client as unversioned files. I am having to delete these files manually for now. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I have used this client for years in Mac with no issues. Recently, I
>   switched my file system to a shared Network drive in a machine with
>   CentOS 7 with SAMBA file sharing.

You should not store a working copy on a network share and especially if you are not the only user who access this share. Most likely, those duplicate files are created by the share for some backup purposes. Check the share's configuration settings.